# Error with declaring variables in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just want set 2 arrays which should contain `for loop` output.
Here's code:

```
var key_ls = new Array();
var value_ls = new Array();
for (var a in window.localStorage) {
   key_ls[a] = a; 
   value_ls[a] = localStorage[a];
}
```

and it gives me no result. What do i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is `key_ls.push(a)`, which will simply add another item to the array. Also use `[]` instead of `new Array()`.

Comment: Sure, will do it after 5 min